# Strange variable initialization in Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I started reading the [section on Node.js](https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html) in the online copy of [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/) (BTW, a well-done book). All examples use the following construct to capture the result of a `require()` call:

```
const {fs} = require("fs");
```

If I try to reproduce this in my node.js 8.9.3 64 bits, the resulting `fs` variable is undefined. A more usual construct:

```
const fs = require("fs");
```

instead returns a usable variable.

My question. I'm missing something obvious? (Maybe I simply have to read the book from the beginning...). Which benefits the first construct gives instead of the more normal variable definition? Thanks!

Comment: Hey.. in the book, it's not `const {fs} = require('fs');` it's `const {readFile} = require('fs');`

Comment: This is object destructuring introduced in ES6

Comment: *Which benefits the first construct gives* This construct is called as a destructing pattern. What it does is, if an object has 10 properties, importing this object and using 1 property with `object.property` every where is a bit of a messy style. It has lot of extra typing and more importantly, consumer has access to lot more than required. This pattern only fetches specific property you specify. This enables devs to keep code clean and every part of code should have access to what is necessary

Comment: Thanks! I tried simply to reduce the number of keystrokes... Missing completely the spirit of the example. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6, you can destruct objects like this:

```
const obj = {first: 1, second: 2};
const {first, second} = obj;

console.log(first,second); // 1 2
```

Similarly, Node's `fs` has a member `readFile` that is being used like:

```
const {readFile} = require('fs');
```

Comment: So it is similar in spirit to Python's `from datetime import datetime` instead of a simple `import datetime`

Comment: This works with every object and not just `requires`, so, maybe that's different.

Comment: Yes, it is more general. I was simply comparing doing `const fs = require("fs");` and then `fs.readFile(...)` to `const {readFile} = require('fs');` and then `readFile(...)`. I'm used to the old js, and often forget the ES6 fantastic additions, but I'm improving...

Comment: Yeah, in that way, they are similar